# cannot delete row key

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-0.7

I'm having an issue while deleting row key in Cassandra. Whenever I delete Row Key all the columns contained by that RowKey are deleted but RowKey itself is not deleted. Can anybody tell me how to remove a rowkey, once it is inserted in columnfamily.

I'm looking forward to do that via thrift client.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When I remove rows in Cassandra I delete only columns not row keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981483/when-i-remove-rows-in-cassandra-i-delete-only-columns-not-row-keys)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a side effect of how distributed deletes work in Cassandra. From the [Cassandra wiki page on distributed deletes](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/DistributedDeletes):

> [A] delete operation can't just wipe out all traces of the data being removed immediately: if we did, and a replica did not receive the delete operation, when it becomes available again it will treat the replicas that did receive the delete as having missed a write update, and repair them! So, instead of wiping out data on delete, Cassandra replaces it with a special value called a tombstone. The tombstone can then be propagated to replicas that missed the initial remove request.

Also take a look at this question on the FAQ: [Why do deleted keys show up during range scans?](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/FAQ#range_ghosts)